# Causatif avec complement d'objet indirect

Tags: pronoms, verbes, constructions, compléments, constructions-causatives

Bonjour a tous.te.s

I am looking for some help with the causative in this sentence:

"Elle _____ fait jouer à des jeux"
(the _____ is the preceding direct object pronoun for "les automobilistes" - either *les* or *leur*)

In all the examples of the causative I have seen, both receiver and agent are *direct* object pronouns; here, since *jouer à des jeux* is a COI, should the preceding object pronoun be *les* or *leur*?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

> Elle **les** fait jouer à des jeux

It would be "*leur*" if it replaced *à + <plural>*.

> Elle fait peur **à ses employés**. Elle **leur** fait peur.
>
> J'ai donné un cadeau **à mes enfants**. Je **leur** ai donné un cadeau.

There is also a *à* in your sentence, but it's not replaced by the pronoun. Here, you're looking for a pronoun that replaces "*les automobilistes*", not "*aux automobilistes*", so it's "*les*", not "*leur*".

Answer (score 2):

Elle les fait jouer à des jeux

i.e.

Elle fait jouer les automobilistes à des jeux